# How I can create a loop for all items from a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a complex problem and all I find don't help me. So I have a `WindowsFormApp` and in `Form2` I have a `CheckedListBox` who is like this :

```
|_|Simulink
|_|Aerospace Blockset
|_|Bioinformatics
```

and many others rows.

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I want, when I check one of this `checkBoxes` to get the name: `Simulink`, for exemple, if `Simulink` is checked or `Aer...` and verify in a text file `instaler.ini` who is here :

```
string installerfilename = Path + "installer.ini";
var link = (Path + "installer.ini").ToString();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(link);
```

where I have that name: `Simulink` after `#product=`, like this : `#product=Simulink` and there delete `#`, and add a `#` where I have `product=all`=> `#product=all` (this is for all cases ).
You can help me to create a loop for all `checkboxes`, because all I tried was to make an event for `checkboxes` but is to complicated, and in that mode I have a lot of code ?

Comment: You need a CheckedListBox control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You simply want list of all checkboxes which are selected, right?

Comment: yes, and after I have to make changes in text file...

Comment: SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @ben If user checks multiple items "Simulink" and "Bioinformatics" , which item you have update in text file in "#product="

Comment: In the text file I have " #product=...." for all items. That means in text file I have "#product=Bioinformatics"

Comment: So if the user check "Simulink" and "Bioinformatics " in text file we will change " #product=Simulink" =>"product=Simulink" and "#product=Bioinformatics"=> "product=Bioinformatics" and "product=all" =>"#product=all"

Comment: and 3."product=all" to "#product=all"

Comment: you need to change in on checked change event or button submit event(i.e after user checked and click submit button)?

Comment: yes ... and if he uncheck a checkbox to return : " product=Simulink"  to " #product=Simulink"

Comment: @Chandru you can help me ? you understand  what I want to say ?

Comment: @ben I have updated my code, check it out. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex.Replace and string.replace to update your product text files.

```
    private void chklbproduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string installerfilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Installer.txt");
        IEnumerable<string> inilines = File.ReadAllLines(installerfilename).AsEnumerable();

        string selectedItem = chklbproduct.SelectedItem.ToString();
        bool IsChecked = chklbproduct.CheckedItems.Contains(selectedItem);

        if (IsChecked)
            inilines = inilines.Select(line => line == string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem) 
                                               ? line.Replace(line, string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem), string.Format(@"product={0}", selectedItem))
                                               : line);

        else
            inilines = inilines.Select(line => (line == string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem) || line == string.Format(@"product={0}", selectedItem)) 
                                               ? line.Replace(line, string.Format(@".*product={0}", selectedItem), string.Format(@"#product={0}", selectedItem)) 
                                               : line);


        if (chklbproduct.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
            inilines = inilines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @".*product=all", @"product=all"));
        else
            inilines = inilines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @".*product=all", @"#product=all"));


        string strWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inilines.ToArray());
        File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, strWrite);

    }
```

Comment: change the path of the installer, before you integrate.

Comment: Ok it works, but I have an additional problem :D ... In items of CheckedListBox I have : Simulink, Simulink Control Design, Simulink Fixed Point, and in text file: 1.#product=Simulink 2.#product=Simulink Control Design 3.#product=Simulink Fixed Point. When I check in list Simulink in text file I will have : 1.product=Simulink 2.product=Simulink Control Design 3.product=Simulink Fixed Point. How I can make, when Simulink is checked just 
#product=Simulink to be modify?

Comment: Works  :*. Thank you !

Comment: I don't be annoying, but you can help me to change the process ? to read in text file and where I have "product=...." without  # in front to check the box. For example if in text file I have  1."#product=all" and 2."product=Simulink" and 3."product=Gauges Blockset" then check in CheckedListBox  Simulink and Gauges Blockset

Comment: and if I have in text file "product=all" without  "#" in front, to check all the check boxes

Answer (score 0):

Assign each checkBox a name by clicking on it in the designer and then filling in the name property in the properties pane. You can now easily reference the checkboxes in code behind

[image: Property pane with name highlighted]

Now in code behind you can create a list from all checkboxes yourself. Be sure to do this **after** calling the `InitializeComponent` method in the constructor.

```
public class MyForm
{
    List<CheckBox> checkboxes;

    public MyForm()
    {
        // Call InitializeComponent first
        // or all the checkboxes will be null
        InitializeComponent();

        checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
        checkboxes.add(myCheckBox1);
        checkboxes.add(myCheckBox2); 
        // etc...
    }
}
```

You can now loop over your checkboxes and perform the necessary actions, for example when a button is clicked:

```
public void Button1_Clicked(...)
{

    // Loop over all checkboxes that are checked
    foreach(var checkbox in checkboxes.Where(x => x.Checked))
    {
        switch(checkbox.Name)
        {
            case "myCheckBox1":
                // MyCheckBox1 is checked, do something
                break;

            case "myCheckBox2":
               // MyCheckBox2 is checked, do something
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't clicking on each item, because It's like a collection, it's not like an individual check box

Comment: In properties panel I have (Name) checkedListBox1, and in Items (Collection) I have the name of the checkboxes

Comment: Your idea it's so good, but please say me how I can assign the name of the checkboxes because I'm restricted and I can't access your link